# Not searching for view in Areas folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm new to areas, so forgive me if I miss some relevant details.

I am trying to hit a page called "Birthday" for which there is a view "Birthday.cshtml". My url looks like `http://example.com/en-us/Event/Birthday`. When I attempt to go to the url, the browser shows me this error:

```
The view 'Birthday' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Event/Birthday.aspx
~/Views/Event/Birthday.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Birthday.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Birthday.ascx
~/Views/Event/Birthday.cshtml
~/Views/Event/Birthday.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Birthday.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Birthday.vbhtml
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not looking in the `~/Areas/Event/Views/Birthday.cshtml` location.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Areas
    \ Event
        \ Controllers
            - EventController.cs
        \ Models
        \ Views
            - Birthday.cshtml
- EventAreaRegistration.cs
```

EventAreaRegistration looks like this:

```
public class EventAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Event";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Event_default",
            "Event/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Event", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ProjectName.Areas.Event.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs includes these lines:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

RegisterRoutes looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{locale}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", locale = Locale.defaultLocale, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post your `RegisterRoutes` code?

Comment: Show how you render the link.  In many cases you have to use an overload that includes the area, to get razor to render the link correctly.

Comment: @BrentMannering - Added the RegisterRoutes

Comment: @DavidTansey - What link are you referring to? Like an HTML link? I'm just hitting the URL directly

Comment: AHA! Figured it out. The {locale} part of the URL was missing from the EventAreaRegistration.cs MapRoute() function, so that route wasn't actually being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The {locale} part of the URL was missing from the EventAreaRegistration.cs MapRoute() function, so that route wasn't actually being used.

```
public class EventAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Event";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Event_default",
            "{locale}/Event/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Event", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ProjectName.Areas.Event.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change it to
public class EventAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Event";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Event_default",
            "Event/{controller }/{action}/{id}",   //change here add controller
            new { controller = "Event", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ProjectName.Areas.Event.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```